# How to stop this method which is being wrongly initialised in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods

I have made an `if... else` loop that's logically correct (I think), but still it calls a block of code even if I enter "N," which stands for a no.

Here's my code:

```
print "\n"

def reversal
  puts "Hello! Let's reverse your name! (Avoid capitals!)\n"
  name = gets.chomp
  puts "YOUR REVERSED NAME IS!!\n"+name.reverse+"\n\n(Press enter to continue)"
  input = gets.chomp
  print "So, did you like it? Y or N!\n"
  feedback = gets.chomp
end

reversal

if feedback = "Y" || feedback = "y" || feedback = "Yes" || feedback = "YES" || feedback = "yes"
  puts "Cool! Would you like to try again? Y or N!\n"
  nestedfeedback = gets.chomp

  if nestedfeedback = "Y" || nestedfeedback = "y" || nestedfeedback = "Yes" || nestedfeedback = "yes" || nestedfeedback = "YES"
    reversal
  end
else
  puts "I'm sorry for that..."
end
```

And I'm attaching a picture of what happens here (I'm entering N, but the code block/method is called anyway):

[image: wrongly initialised method]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`feedback=gets.chomp` will define a local variable, only visible inside `reversal`. When you test it outside `reversal`, it would be `nil`, since it has not been defined in that context.

Also, `if feedback="Y"...` will *define* `feedback` to be `"Y"`, not test if it is. Since `"Y"` and all the other varieties are all truthy, the `if` will always succeed.

Among many things you can do is:

- Use the fact that `feedback` is a return value from `reversal`, and use this in the main code instead plain `reversal`:

  ```
  feedback = reversal
  ```
- Test your variables with `==` in the `if`.

Comment: Then what should I use: `if feedback='Y'` or `if feedback=="Y"` or `if feedback=Y`?

Comment: The first one will assign `'Y'` to feedback. The second one will test if `feedback` is `"Y"`. The third one will try to see if the value of the variable `feedback` is the same as the value of the constant `Y`, which you have not defined, and would give you an error.

Comment: And can I just put a $feedback="No" in the very beginning of the entire code?

Comment: That would make it a global variable, and you'd have to write `$feedback` instead of `feedback` throughout your code. Also, global variables are kind of dangerous, better not get used to them. But, to answer your questions, that is indeed another of the "many things you can do".

Answer (score 0):

why dont you make feedback

```
feedback.downcase!
```

so that you dont have to worry about cases.

Comment: Should I make `$feedback` `$feedback.downcase` when I declare it in the very top? Or do I have to append it at all places?

Comment: if you do feedback.downcase! you don't have to repeat. it will stay downcase.